# Infinite Wilson Prime proof

Tags: prime-numbers, proof-writing

An article I read recently about Wilson Primes stated that, while 5, 13, and 563 are the only known terms, there is an infinite number of Wilson Primes. I was wondering if someone could verify this with a proof.
Thanks

Comment: Was it an article or a Numberphile video? :P

Comment: You caught me Darth Geek

Comment: I took a screenshot and tweeted it to Brady, if that's ok with you :D

Answer (score 3):

According to Wikipedia it is merely conjecture whether or not there are infinitely many Wilson primes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson_prime), in other words, there is no proof of this. :)